# Problema de conexión con base de datos

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo 2 servidores en la misma red. Uno de ellos, es un servidor web *Fedora 28* en el que tengo un formulario que quiero conectar a la base de datos. El otro, es un *Windows Server 2008* que contiene el *SQL Server 2012*.

He intentado conectarlos de varias formas, ninguna me ha servido y sigo con el problema.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Este es el código que tengo

```
<?php
    function FormatErrors( $errors )
    {

     /* Display errors. */

     echo "Error information: <br/>";


      if(!$errors || is_array($errors) ) {
           return ;
      }

     foreach ( $errors as $error );

     {

     echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br/>";

     echo "Code: ".$error['code']."<br/>";

     echo "Message: ".$error['message']."<br/>";

     }

    }

$q = isset($_GET['q'])? intval($_GET['q']) : 0;
$serverName = "****IP****:**PORT***";
$conInfo = array ( "Database"=>"**DATABASE**", "UID"=>"**USR**", "PWD"=>"**PASS**");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conInfo);
if ($con) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br>";
}else{
    echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br>";
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

    sqlsrv_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM prueba1 WHERE codigo = '".$q."'";

    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);

    if ($getResults == FALSE) {

      die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }

    $cantidad_encontrado = sqlsrv_num_rows($getResults);

    if ($cantidad_encontrado > 0) {
           echo "<table>
                  <tr>
                  <th>Código</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellidos</th>
                  <th>Proyecto</th>
                  </tr>";  

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults)) {
                echo "<tr>";                                 
                echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['apellidos'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['proyecto'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
    sqlsrv_close($con);

    }else{
        echo "<h1>NO ENCONTRE DATOS </h1>";
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
          <option value="">Select a person:</option>
          <option value="1">Luis</option>
          <option value="2">Nora</option>
          <option value="3">Aron</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="txtHint"><b>Selecciona tu nombre</b></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Incluso haciendo solo una prueba de conexión, sigue saltándome el error 500.

```
<?php
$serverName = "**SERVER**"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"**DATABASE**", "UID"=>"**USER", "PWD"=>"**PASS**");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

En el *SQL Server* tengo los puertos abiertos, excepciones de firewall, tanto para la aplicación, la IP y el puerto. Uso es usuario *sa* de *SQL*, ya que es el concedido para las conexiones remotas. También tengo habilitado las conexiones *TCP/IP* en el *SQL Server*.

También he instalado las librerías de *PHP*, tanto en el servidor *SQL* como los *archivos .so* en el servidor web.

Aquí el *php.ini*, la configuración de *sqlsrv*

```
[SQL Server]

;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.so
;extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts.so
extension= /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

Si hago un `php -m` salen los módulos *sqlsrv* y *pdo_sqlsrv* , pero en phpinfo.php no sale nada de la extensión sqlsrv.

Aún con todo eso, sigue sin funcionar. Ya no se me ocurren más ideas, o si algo hice mal y no sé el qué.

Comment: Para descartar tema de Firewalls... podrías hacer alguna de estas dos cosas: 1) Un telnet desde el servidor fedora al servidor windows con el puerto de la bbdd. o 2) Instalar en el servidor windows un php, o Xampp o similar y establecer un script simple de conexión contra localhost.

Comment: Hola Lucía. ¿Lograste finalmente instalar los controladores en el servidor Fedora?  ¿Los controladores ahora sí se ven en `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @Julio acabo de probarlo con Telnet, se conecta por el puerto, sí

Comment: @A.Cedano lo probé unas cuantas veces más y sigue sin funcionar, se que el problema tiene un 80% de posibilidades de estar ahí, pero no lo consigo de ninguna forma

Comment: Pero ¿el controlador se ve o no en `phpinfo()`?

Comment: No, no se ve. Y no entiendo porqué

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar qué configuración tienes en el `php.ini` con respecto a `sqlsrv`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102245/discussion-between-lucia-and-a-cedano).